# Attempting to Auto-populate Lookup Field using Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm having issues creating an Apex Trigger, I'm fairly new to the salesforce platform. I'm attempting to auto-populate a lookup field that refers back to the staff page.

```
trigger HomeDepotStore on i360__Sale__c(before insert, before update) {
for (i360__Sale__c a: Trigger.new) {
   list<i360__Staff__c> stafflist = [select id from i360__Staff__c where i360__Staff__c.Name =:a.Referral_Store__c];
    if (a.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c == null) {
        a.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c = staffList[0].id;
    }
}
}
```

Each store has its own Staff account with its own ID. There is already a field a.Referral_Store__c that has the store number filled out. The idea is to select the id of the staff that has a Name that is equal to that Referral Store variable. My current issue is that when I run it against my Apex Test Class I receive no "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject." I'll also include my Apex test class below. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I feel like I'm missing something incredibly simple.

```
        @isTest
        private class HomeDepotStoreTest {
            static testMethod void TestHomeDepotStores() {
                i360__Prospect__c Pros = new i360__Prospect__c();
                Pros.Name = 'Bob Joe';
                Pros.Referral_Store__c = '2036';
                Pros.i360__Phone_1__c = '(123) 123-1234';
                Pros.i360__Primary_Last_Name__c = 'TESTMCTEST';
                insert Pros;
                i360__Appointment__c App = new i360__Appointment__c();
                App.Name = '2036';
                App.i360__Prospect__c = [SELECT i360__Prospect__c.i360__Prospect_Id_String__c FROM i360__Prospect__c WHERE i360__Prospect__c.Name = : ('2036')].Id;
                i360__Sale__c a = new i360__Sale__c();
                a.Name = '2036';
                insert a;
                i360__Staff__c staff = new i360__Staff__c();
                staff.Name = '2036';
                staff.Id = 'a0j0a00000ADi2yAAD';
                insert staff;
            }
        }
```

I made a few tweaks and took your suggestions on how to write a proper Apex Trigger. Thanks so much guys!

```
public class HomeDepotStoreHandler extends TriggerHandler {    
/* context overrides */
public Id getStaffid() {
    i360__Sale__c sa = new i360__Sale__c();
    List <i360__Staff__c> staffid = [select id from i360__Staff__c where i360__Staff__c.Name 
                 =: sa.Referral_Store__c];
    return staffid[0].Id;
}
   protected override void beforeUpdate() {
i360__Sale__c a = new i360__Sale__c();
if (a.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c == null) {
    a.HD_Base_Store_Our_System__c = getStaffid();
   }    
 }
}
```

Comment: Never query within a loop!

Comment: @AdrianLarson Dang, how did I miss that.

Comment: It's easier to catch if you follow [trigger best practice](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) and use logic-less triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with the trigger and the test class, but to answer the scope of this question:

Your issue is that you're inserting the `i360__Sale__c` record (which causes the trigger to run) before you insert the `i360__Staff__c` record, so when the query is executed in your trigger, there is no match for the `2036` value. Basically this is what's happening, in order:

1. sale record is inserted
2. trigger runs, queries for staff record in database, finds no match, throws exception

I would advise first modifying your trigger code to follow best practices (Adrian linked) before fixing the QueryException. I am also fairly certain that once you fix the QueryException, this line is going to throw a different exception:

```
staff.Id = 'a0j0a00000ADi2yAAD';
```

This should be ommitted altogether.

One other thing, because it will save you time - this line:

```
App.i360__Prospect__c = [SELECT i360__Prospect__c.i360__Prospect_Id_String__c FROM i360__Prospect__c WHERE i360__Prospect__c.Name = : ('2036')].Id;
```

can be changed to `App.i360__Prospect__c = Pros.Id;`

Once a record has been inserted, its Id has been generated, and you can set the relationship directly from the variable.

Comment: Definitely should've cleaned it up slightly before putting it on here. I was getting odd errors so I started putting nonsense code to see if something stuck. Thanks for pointing out the error with the staff though.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the heads up on the ID, I wasn't sure whether in a test environment that it was created or not.